# Change the root path for all ajax (mod rewrite)

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My all the ajax calls lie inside the js files and calls are done using jquery. I was using relative url in these files for the ajax call.
I just implemented pretty urls and all the ajax calls have stopped working + All the css,images and links stopped working.

I fixed the images,css,js includes by using
    `<link href="<?php echo ROOT; ?>/myfile.css" rel=stylesheet />`
where ROOT -> root path for my website
So, i switched over to absolute urls.

But still i cannot figure out a way to modify urls in ajax calls as i cannot use `<?php echo ROOT; ?>` inside a .js file.

```
$.post('relativeUrl.php',params,function(){

});
```

Anybody have a solution for this. Thanks in advance.
Please ask for clarification if I didn't explained things well

Comment: You could use `location.host` to get the absolute path

Comment: @Jerodev I have a problem using location.host .When using http://localhost/mywebsite/mypath/dynamicName/dynamicMore , it will show localhost instead of localhost/mywebsite.